# Combine two functions under the same name without overloading

Tags: scala, overloading

Here is the code:

```
 def transform1(f: String => String): Unit = {
    val s = getString
    f.andThen(putString)(s)
  }

  def transform2(f: String => Option[String]): Unit = {
    val s = getString
    f(s).foreach(putString(_))
  }
```

How do you express these two ideas in one single function?
Method overloading does not work and seems discouraged by the community.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Seems that two ideas belong into two separate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand that why anyone may want this but here is a way to do it:

```
def transform(f: Either[(String => String), (String => Option[String])]: Unit = f match {
   case Left(f) => // do transform1 here
   case Right(f) => //do transform2 here
}
```

As I said at the begining you probably shouldn't want to do this; perhaps you should directly ask what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern to avoid overloading is to convert disparate arguments to a common, specific type. There could be any number of such conversions.

Not sure this is the most compelling example, however.

```
object X {
  trait MapFlat[-A, +B] { def apply(x: A): B }
  implicit class mapper[A](val f: A => A) extends MapFlat[A, A] {
    override def apply(x: A) = {
      val res = f(x)
      println(res)
      res
    }
  }
  implicit class flatmapper[A](val f: A => Option[A]) extends MapFlat[A, Option[A]] {
    override def apply(x: A) = {
      val res = f(x)
      res foreach println
      res
    }
  }
  def f[B](g: MapFlat[String, B]) = {
    g("abc")
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  import X._
  f((s: String) => s)
  f((s: String) => Some(s))
}
```

Comment: For more info about using a common type, see the [magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it will be type classes, here's a sample -

```
trait Transformer[T] {
  def transform(foo: String => T)
}

object Transformer {

  implicit object StringTransformer extends Transformer[String] {
    override def transform(foo: (String) => String): Unit = ??? // Your logic here
  }

  implicit object OptStringTransformer extends Transformer[Option[String]] {
    override def transform(foo: (String) => Option[String]): Unit = ??? // Your logic here
  }

}

class SampleClass {
  def theOneTransformYouWant[T: Transformer](f: String => T) = {
    implicitly[Transformer[T]].transform(f)
  }

  def canUseBothWays(): Unit = {
    theOneTransformYouWant((s: String) => s)
    theOneTransformYouWant((s: String) => Some(s))
  }
}
```

Another way would be the magnet pattern
http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/

```
sealed trait TransformationMagnet {
  def apply(): Unit
}

object TransformationMagnet {
  implicit def fromString(f: String => String): TransformationMagnet =
    new TransformationMagnet {
      def apply(): Unit = ??? // Your code goes here
    }

  implicit def fromOptString(f: String => Option[String]): TransformationMagnet =
    new TransformationMagnet {
      def apply(): Unit = ??? // your code goes here
    }
}


class SampleClass {
  def theOneTransformYouWant(f: TransformationMagnet) = {
    ???
  }

  def hereWeUseItInBothWays(): Unit = {
    theOneTransformYouWant((s: String) => s)
    theOneTransformYouWant((s: String) => Some(s))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new parameter on the description `typeOfTransform`

add a conditional inside the function

```
 if (typeOfTransform == type1){ 
 //functionality1
 }else {
 //functionality2
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, you can actually overload methods like this by adding implicit arguments which will always be available:

```
def transform(f: String => Option[String]): Unit = ...
def transform(f: String => String)(implicit d: DummyImplicit): Unit = ...
```